# Separating your publications into journals vs. conference/workshop

Tags: publications, cv, website

It seems typical in some fields (e.g. engineering) for researchers to classify their publications on their websites and CVs into two groups: journal vs. conference/workshop. This appears to be because journal papers are considered more significant, in some sense.

This doesn't appear to be the case in other fields, such as computer science, where conferences are seen as more significant. With more people in engineering publishing in top CS venues, and the lines between the two fields becoming a bit blurry, the reasoning for separating papers into journal vs. not journal isn't clear.

**Question:** What is a good strategy for organizing publications in on a website/CV?

Comment: Could you phrase the question so that it does not look like a poll? The Stack Exchange model works better for questions that have a definite answer.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Thanks, I've edited the question

Comment: It is still just a poll. How about: What is a good strategy for organizing publications in a CV?

Answer (score 4):

Even in Computer Science fields where conferences reign, it can still be worthwhile to categorize publications. For instance, I currently divide them into journals, book chapters, major conferences, specialized conferences, abstracts, and non-peer reviewed. (These are automatically put into my web page as well, but there I only distinguish between long and short papers.) Each paper is also marked with the acceptance rate, where appropriate. What is the value in doing this:

1. Journals show a depth of work. Having some work in each category means that you aren't only publishing in conferences -- that when research needs a deeper treatment you are working to provide it. (In CS I have far fewer journal publications than would be expected in Engineering.)
2. Specialized venues can illustrate involvement in smaller communities, and it is often easier to take leadership in such communities. These communities might also know a specialized area better, meaning that there is better vetting of ideas.
3. Separating non-peer reviewed papers seems necessary from an ethical perspective - they are a different category. I put this in the last section where it sometimes indicates invited papers that go along with a keynote.
4. Breaking things up allows someone to quickly see the breakdown of where you are publishing to notice points like the above. I often distrust one monolithic list because it's hard to see where work is actually going.

Overall, I suggest that breaking things up facilitates the fast read and avoid any ethical issues about artificially inflating your CV.

Answer (score 2):

I happen to prefer a chronological listing. But it is really up to you. For example, if you work regularly in two different research areas you could even list publications and such separately for the two areas.

The chronological listing makes it easier, IMO, to follow a thread or trend in research where other divisions don't.

But, if you have access to examples of how others do it in your field it would probably be best to follow along.

You are asking here for what amounts to opinion and those opinions may not be valid in your field. Do what is expected, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to sound negative but I agree with the others, this question looks awfully like a poll. So a reframing might be a good idea.

Speaking about the CV, the **only** thing that matters is the perspective of the reader. On average a CV is glanced at for 30-45 secs, if interesting then read for an additional minute or two. In that light, the only sensible thing to do is to put what matters to the reader first and easily distinguishable.

So if you are applying for an academic position or a position where academic merits are important, and work in a field where journal papers are valued highly, you put (possibly a selection of) your papers in reverse chronological order, so that the most recent/relevant one comes first.

If you are applying to industry where conferences might have higher value, then you highlight them. Or if you have given talks at big international conference you might want to focus on them instead.

There is no one-size fits all here.

As for your own personal homepage, where you have your bio without any intent of application and/or particular audience in mind, then do whatever you feel like. It's your own page! :)